# Parsing Map Object through http request in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm very confused about something. I'm trying to send a `Map<string, string[]>` through a request and it is working fine in Angular 9.1 but it stopped working when I upgraded to Angular 13. I didn't find anything related to changes being made to the HttpClient or so.

I've found this issue on GitHub **Serialization of JSON bodies containing a Typescript Map object**: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32117

And the answer they provided is:

> Unfortunately HttpClient uses a simple JSON.stringify call to
> serialize bodies to JSON. This call doesn't support what you'd like to
> do with Map objects.
>
> I suggest using an HttpInterceptor to modify outgoing request bodies
> before they're serialized, and convert Maps to POJ(s)Os.

But I'm wondering, why am I able to successfully perform the request in Angular 9.1 but can't in Angular 13?

Here's the code example:

```
export interface MyObject {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  labels?: Map<string, string[]>;
}

this.http.post<AlertRule>(url, myObjectInstance).pipe(
    catchError(this.errorHandler.handlerHTTPError)
);
```

The problem is that the object actually sent does not contain our Map fields in Angular 13 but it does in Angular 9.

```
{
  "name" : "my-name",
  "description" : "my-description",
  "labels" : {}
}
```

**Again**, I know **I can manually convert** the Map<string, string[]> to JSON to get this working. But my question is, why this is working on an older version and why I didn't find anything related to this change in the upgrade guide? If there was one.

Could this be related to RxJS, Nodejs, or TypeScript instead of Angular?

Comment: Are you really sure it was a map and not secretly a plain javascript object? I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to work in Angular 9 too.

Comment: Created a Stackblitz to double check it. The object posted to example.com contains an empty map: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jk33q2?file=package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. I have it working right now in Angular 9 without making any manual conversion, just sending the Map as it is. But when I go to the 13 version it just stops working and I need to make a manual conversion.

Comment: Maybe a http interceptor or some kind of dependency which isn't compatible with Angular 13?

Comment: So may this be related to any change on how Map works in Typescript?

Comment: I'm not aware of any change which might have caused this. I think you have to find out where the map is converted since I think it's done outside of Angular. You could add something like this for debugging purposes to find out where it's called:

`Object.defineProperty(myObjectInstance, 'labels', {
      get: function () {
        debugger; // This breakpoint should be hit somewhere I guess.. 
        return myObjectInstance.labels;
      }
  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused because `core-js@2` implemented a Map.prototype.toJSON proposal, but it was rejected by TC39, so it was removed from `core-js@3`.

[Reference](https://github.com/DavidBruant/Map-Set.prototype.toJSON)